# CakePHP Debug_Kit won't work on Beanstalk

Tags: php, cakephp, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, content-management-system

I've been having quite some issues with CakePHP, I'm pretty new to it so that's understandable but I can't seem to find any answers to my issues.

Firstly, I'm getting the `DebugKit is not able to connect to the database. The datasource configuration "debug_kit" was not found.` I've seen that people usually get this when pdo_sqlite isn't enabled or installed, but I've confirmed that it's loaded:

[image]

For some reason from time to time I get `Your tmp directory is NOT writable.` although I've given my tmp folder 777 permissions.

All this ultimately results in `Table class for alias TABLENAME could not be found.` while deleting users on my server, but it works locally for me (even with the same run commands).

I've set the proper relations between the tables so I really have no idea what to do.

P.S.

I've tried forcing DebugKit with `Configure::write('DebugKit.forceEnable', TRUE);` and I get `Missing Database configuration` error (so pretty much the same thing)

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple things going on here.

#### DebugKit database connection

The DebugKit plugin (which ships with CakePHP) is expecting a database connection named `debug_kit` to be configured among your datasources. Datasources are typically configured in `app.php`, but they can also be configured on the fly such as [in the test bootstrapper](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3a5e956309014d4b79a670440e178dd02cd4a778/tests/bootstrap.php#L39).

To clear up this error, define a `debug_kit` array entry under the `Datasources` key in `app.php` or `app_local.php`. You can use SQLite if you want, or just another database on your default connection.

#### Permissions of `tmp/` and `logs/`

This is a common problem for many newer CakePHP developers. There is an [official solution for setting permissions](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/installation.html#permissions) in the docs:

```
HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
setfacl -R -m u:${HTTPDUSER}:rwx tmp
setfacl -R -d -m u:${HTTPDUSER}:rwx tmp
setfacl -R -m u:${HTTPDUSER}:rwx logs
setfacl -R -d -m u:${HTTPDUSER}:rwx logs
```

However, this ought to have been set up for you when you ran `composer install`. If it wasn't, try running it again (assuming a bash-like shell).

Just some other quick notes on some other things you said:

- `Configure::write('DebugKit.forceEnable', TRUE);` does not do what you think it does, it force-enables the plugin on non-allowlisted domains & TLDs.  Recommend leaving this as-is except in rare circumstances.
- `Table class for alias TABLENAME could not be found.` This is an extremely generic error message and gives no indication of why the table itself could not be found (there are a myriad of reasons). Look for additional details in the error message for clues.

Comment: Also, these are not problems unique to Elastic Beanstalk. These are just problems with the CakePHP setup in that environment. Fix the environment, fix the app.

Comment: Thanks for the assist man, I already gave up from EB honestly, got caught up with some other work, but I created an EC2 instance and I'll configure everything there without the hassle and I believe everything should work fine. I'll post the result here :)